# Using a Derived class of a Java Swing control to create listener for self

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

At the outset: I know that what I am doing is bad design. I am trying this to get a better feel of Java - what is possible, what is not and why?

I have written the following code:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    import javax.swing.*;

    public class ButtonTest
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    ButtonFrame frame = new ButtonFrame();
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
    {
        private final static int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 300;
        private final static int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 200;
        private final JPanel buttonPanel;

        public ButtonFrame()
        {
            this.setTitle("Button Frame");
            this.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

            PanelButton yellowButton = new PanelButton("Yellow", Color.YELLOW, this);
            PanelButton redButton = new PanelButton("Red", Color.RED, this);
            PanelButton blueButton = new PanelButton("Blue", Color.BLUE, this);

            this.buttonPanel = new JPanel();
            this.buttonPanel.add(yellowButton);
            this.buttonPanel.add(redButton);
            this.buttonPanel.add(blueButton);

            // add panel to frame
            this.add(this.buttonPanel);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class PanelButton extends JButton implements ActionListener
    {
        private final Color buttonColor;
        private final ButtonFrame containingFrame;

        public PanelButton(String title, Color buttonColor,
                ButtonFrame containingFrame)
        {
            super(title);
            this.buttonColor = buttonColor;
            this.containingFrame = containingFrame;
            this.addActionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            this.containingFrame.setBackground(this.buttonColor);
        }
    }
```

But this is not working. I see from the debugger that `actionPerformed()` is being invoked and it has the expected values. I am not able to understand what is happening here. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can skip passing the container and just do

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    this.getParent().setBackground(buttonColor);
}
```

Comment: +1 for a separate solution. Mine was to explain why his didn't work, and yours shows how to do it better. Good duality there.

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the background color of the `JFrame`, but the `JPanel` that is contained by the `JFrame`, which then holds your buttons, takes up all of the space of the `JFrame`, so you can't see the background color changing.

This works.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ButtonTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                ButtonFrame frame = new ButtonFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ButtonFrame extends JFrame
{
    private final static int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 300;
    private final static int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 200;
    private final JPanel buttonPanel;

    public ButtonFrame()
    {
        this.setTitle("Button Frame");
        this.setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);

        this.buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        PanelButton yellowButton = new PanelButton("Yellow", Color.YELLOW, buttonPanel);
        PanelButton redButton = new PanelButton("Red", Color.RED, buttonPanel);
        PanelButton blueButton = new PanelButton("Blue", Color.BLUE, buttonPanel);

        this.buttonPanel.add(yellowButton);
        this.buttonPanel.add(redButton);
        this.buttonPanel.add(blueButton);

        // add panel to frame
        this.add(this.buttonPanel);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class PanelButton extends JButton implements ActionListener
{
    private final Color buttonColor;
    private final JPanel buttonPanel;

    public PanelButton(String title, Color buttonColor,
            JPanel buttonPanel)
    {
        super(title);
        this.buttonColor = buttonColor;
        this.buttonPanel = buttonPanel;
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        buttonPanel.setBackground(this.buttonColor);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the miss. I like the other solution better since it hides the fact about what type the container belongs to and is, hence, more useful in other scenarios also.

Comment: But, of course! Yes, the other solution is better, but I felt that you should understand why you encountered the problem (because that is what you asked!). :P. Happy programming!

Comment: I love most complex examples +1